# When your teeth are covered by plaque

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

What do you usually say when your teeth are covered by plaque? Or what a doctor would say to you in order to suggest you to get a teeth cleaning:

What comes to my mind is:

> - I have a bad case of plaque.

Or

> - My teeth have been covered with plaque.  [this sounds to be more correct to me in English, but I doubt.]

If no one is naturally correct, then please tell me what to say to the doctor or what to say to the patient as a dentist?

Answer (score 1):

You would simply say

> My teeth are covered with [plaque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_plaque).

*Plaque* is colorless but can cause yellowing of the teeth.

The hard white deposits in teeth is called *[tartar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_(dental))* and is a side effect of plaque.

If you wanted to emphasize the amount of plaque on your teeth, you might say

> I have plaque *buildup* on my teeth.

"Plaque" is usually understood to be on your teeth, although the term is also used for fatty deposit buildup in one's arteries.

To imply it indirectly, you might say

> I need to get my teeth cleaned.

People will understand that your have plaque and tartar build up which needs to be addressed and it would be understood to be significant since people will not usually volunteer to visit the dentist, and they may won't kiss you since cavities can be transmitted by kissing.

Comment: Let's improve my thread. I had to explain it a bit more. So, the problem is that how can I intensify the sentence: "My teeth are covered with plaque." @Peter?